Reverse Proxy Redirect not working as expected
I have a VPS where i hosted an Appwrite Instance. I also have a domain that is linked to the server and the behaviour i want to achieve is that when a user calls just the baseurl the user should be redirected but if the user calls the baseurl + /appwrite so example.com/appwrite then the user should see the appwrite instance.
This is my current conf in /sites-enabled/:
server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example_private_key.key;
server_name example.com;

location /appwrite/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443/; # Appwrite's internal URL
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    rewrite ^/appwrite/(.*) /$1 break;
}

location / {
    return 301 https://redirect-url.com;
}
}

The current behaviour is that when i call the base-url i am being redirected like i wanted to. If i call example.com/appwrite i get an 404 error and if i call the url example.com:8443 only then i see the appwrite instance.
What am i doing wrong?

For starters you should try withh removing trailing slash from proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443/;, which implies explicit rewrite that may be interfering with the rest of your configuration.

@drookie I tried removing the trailing slash but it still does not work as expected.

Then you should figure out from nginx logs who's really returning the 404 (by adding the upstream code to nginx log format). Is it the nginx or the backend you're proxying it to; could be either one.
